# Passing variable from controller to view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter and OOP PHP.

Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $planet = $this->main_model->solar();
    $this->load->view('main_view', $planet);    
    }
```

If `echo $planet` in the controller it does what it's supposed to do.  If I `echo $planet` in the view I get an undefined variable error.  `$planet` is not an array.  Why isn't the `$planet` variable being passed to the view?

I know this is a simple and basic question and I'm embarrassed that I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:  Okay, after more fiddling around, I got it to work.  Can variables only be passed from Controller to View when they're formatted as an array?

Comment: The answers below are both correct. [CodeIgniter's user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) is really useful. *Adding Dynamic Data to the View* on [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) of the user guide is relevant to your question.

Comment: Variables can be passed from the controller to the view by way of an *object* or an *array*.

Comment: @user1616244 accept one of these answer

Comment: @jleft those hyperlinks seem to be dead.

Answer (score 31):

You have to pass an array to the view. CodeIgniter automatically makes `$planet` available to you.

```
$data = array('planet' => $planet);
$this->load->view('main_view', $data);
```

With this you can use `$planet` in your view.

E.g., if you do the following:

```
$data = array('foo' => 'Hello', 'bar' => 'world');
$this->load->view('main_view', $data);
```

`$foo` and `$bar` will be available in your view. The key-value pairs in the array are automatically converted to variables in the view.

Comment: Is this also how variables need to passed from the Controller to the Model and from the Model back to the Controller?

Comment: No, you can just call a model function and save it in a variable. Like you are already doing in your code: `$planet = $this->main_model->solar();`

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help, guys.  I know this was a pretty basic question.  OOP PHP seems pretty easy, but learning and understanding the MVC model is a bit difficult for me.

Comment: @Mischa sir how this `$data = array('foo' => 'Hello', 'bar' => 'world');` accessed in view page?

Comment: @KUMAR, it becomes a variable in the view, so `$foo` and `$bar`.

Answer (score 13):

You can pass either an *array* or an *object* to the view. You can then access the array key(s) as a variable(s) in your view.

### Controller

**Array**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $planet_data['planet'] = $this->main_model->solar();
    $this->load->view('main_view', $planet_data);
}
```

**Object**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $planet_data = new stdClass(); //Creates a new empty object
    $planet_data->planet = $this->main_model->solar();
    $this->load->view('main_view', $planet_data);
}
```

From <s>[CodeIgniter's user manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)</s>(deadlink): *Note: If you use an object, the class variables will be turned into array elements.*

### View

Regardless of how you pass the data, it can be displayed like this:

```
<?php echo $planet; ?>
```

If it's an array then you would need to iterate through it. Or an object, then access it's member variables.

---

In my experience using an array is more common than using an object.

Comment: i  have read detailed guide about how to pass value from controller to view in codigniter  http://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

Try like:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $data['planet'] = $this->main_model->solar();
    $this->load->view('main_view', $data);    
}
```

and at your views you can access `"$planet"`.

Answer (score 1):

If modal contain array response:

```
public function solar() {
   $data['earth'] = 'Earth';
   $data['venus'] = 'Venus';
   return $data;
}
```

then you the data to view like this:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $planet = $this->main_model->solar();
    $this->load->view('main_view', $planet);    
}
```

But at view you will have access data like this:

```
echo $earth;
echo $venus;
```

if you don't know want response will come then use code like this:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $planet['planet'] = $this->main_model->solar();
    $this->load->view('main_view', $planet);    
}
```

and in view file you can access the data like this:

```
print_r($planet);
```

**If you don't know what data will come into view then just use this code at view:**

```
print_r($this->_ci_cached_vars);
```