# How do I pass a variable from the controller to the view in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller:

```php
$data = array(
    'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
);
$this->load->view('/login/index', $data);
```

View page:

```php
<?php echo $error_message; ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing variable from controller to view in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294527/passing-variable-from-controller-to-view-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Please elaborate the issue that you are facing. what is exactly expected? are you facing any errors?

Comment: Do you getting any error?like view not found.Also you can see https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html which will help you learn it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have put the `view` path wrong and hence the variable is not reaching the `view`. 
This is how it should be,

**Controller:** (applications/controllers/filename.php)

```
$data = array(
    'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
);

$this->load->view('login/index', $data);   # removed slash here
```

**View:** (applications/views/login/index.php)

```
<?php echo $error_message; ?>
```

Comment: Happy to help. You can accept the answer (green tick left to answer).