# How do I retrieve the value of parameter from controller to view?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

These is what I have, I'm using Codeigniter MVC.

CONTROLLER

```
public function index() {

    $sample = "call: 887-65-31";

    $this->load->view('contact_view', $sample);

}
```

now how do i retrieve it on contact view page?

Comment: wow, you didn't even try to search it hah? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294527/passing-variable-from-controller-to-view-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Controller**

```
<?php

class Example extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
       $viewData['sample'] = "call: 887-65-31";
       $this->load->view('contact_view', $viewData);
    }
}
```

**View**

*then **echo in contact_view** like below:*

```
<?php 
   echo $sample;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

Controller:

```
public function index() {

    $sample['phone'] = "call: 887-65-31";

    $this->load->view('contact_view', $sample);

}
```

In View:

You can print `$phone` where you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller:

```
public function index() {

        $sample = "call: 887-65-31";

        $this->load->view('contact_view', $sample);
}
```

In the view:

```
<?php
    echo $sample 
?>
```